IBM UDeploy - Streamline component process
In our current setup with IBM udeploy. We have a separate component process for each AWS endpoint(eg:east-1/east-2/west-2). The only difference between these processes is the API property in the CF shell script for each AWS foundations. This API endpoint is derived from system properties
eg: API =https://api.dev.east1.organisation.com

We aim to streamline this by creating a single component process that can handle all current AWS foundations and any foundations added in future. Based on the location value specified in the version properties (east-1/west-2 etc.,). in Udeploy, the deployment should occur according to the specified location, rather than having multiple API(target endpoint) CF shell script. These deployments are triggered via Jenkins/Cloudbees pipeline.
Could anyone suggest how we might achieve this scenario? any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.
